# how to make a restful endpoint only accessible for specific users?

Tags: java, spring, rest

l have this /getSecret endpoint that retrieves secret from the database, but l don't want to make it accessible for everyone but only for specific users, how can l do that?

Comment: do not share with it anyone, only share with the `specific users`, other famous secret is  `authorisation`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a specific authentication like OAuth2.The implementation depends on the technologies you are using. Can you be more specific?

You can try this out:
https://www.baeldung.com/rest-api-spring-oauth2-angular

Comment: l am using spring for the restful api

Comment: You should tag java and spring on your question